# QBO REST API - Allow user to pick their company

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

The Intuit API Browser does something I would like to do in my application. It authenticates you and then provides a dropdown box that allows you tin interact with one or more tenants that your account may have access to.

How can I duplicate this behavior in my app?

I would expect that I could call:

https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/

To get back a list of all companies I have access to.

Searching the doco doesn't show anything like this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get a list of companies for a particular user.  The OAuth flow will only grant tokens for 1 company (realm).

Comment: Thanks Peter. Thoughts on how the API Explorer: https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO does this?

Comment: No problem.  Its an internal Intuit application so it has rights to a user's realm list.